# Are there any security flaws when exposing local sites via Ngrok?

Tags: security, tunneling, ngrok

I am really addicted to exposing my local sites via Ngrok for remote testing and I love it! But I might end up making my pc becoming vulnerable to internet attacks.

Although I read this [NGROK – THE TOOL...](http://blog.reybango.com/2015/05/13/ngrok-the-tool-that-brings-local-site-testing-to-remoteie/) and this [Tunnelling...](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2015/01/tunnelling-docker-container-using-ngrok/) and they both state that Ngrok Supports **Secure Tunnels to localhost**

Are there any other things I must worry about with regards to security whilst using this tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ngrok only exposes `80` and `443` you're basically only as vulnerable as the underlying app server that is being exposed (modulo bugs in ngrok, but for the sake of argument assume there are none).